# Add htmlContent via Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\ModifierInterface

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form

where i can find an example to add html content in my form using ModifierInterface. Or how to add part of ui_configuration in that modifier?

Answer (score 2):

Find out. Here is an example:

```
'elementName' => [
    'arguments' => [
        'data' => [
            'config' => [
                'componentType' => 'htmlContent',
            ]
        ],
        'block' => $this->blockFactory->createBlock(
            'YourBlockClassName'
        )
     ]
 ]
```

Comment: Great! That helped me a lot.
One question @styopchik, do you know in the block how to get form element value?